# specific java build from Oracle archive

Tags: java

I want to download a specific Java build (1.8.0-b132). I went to the Java archive download link
[Java archive download link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html)

But it is sorted by update, not by build. How do I know which Java update version is the build that I want?

Comment: what java product specifically? Oracle does not generally release dailies for java, for numerous reasons related to their internal release management and QA procedures.

Comment: Based on that version that appears to be a pre-jre 8 release, in other words, a beta release.  What possible reason would you need a vulnerable unstable beta release of Java for?

Comment: JDK, and I need it to resolve a compatibility issue with another software product.